# Join to list in LINQ to SQL (SQL mode)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the table News:

```
public class New
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and every new has a poll, and it's saved in the table NewOptions:

```
public class NewOption
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("New")]
    public int NewId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Option { get; set; }

    public virtual New New { get; set; }
}
```

News 1:M NewOptions
And their respective DTOs. I want get the latest news with their respective options:

```
var news =
    from theNew in this.context.News
    join option in this.context.NewOptions on theNew.Id equals option.NewId
    select new NewDto
    {
        Id = theNew.Id,
        Title = theNew.Title,
        Options = new NewOptionDto
        {
            Id = option.Id,
            Option = option.Option
        }
    };
```

The error is: Can't convert type NewOptionDto to IEnumerable

Comment: You are using reserved names.. You can't use New as name of class.  Change to News.  I think some of the errors will go away.  Public virtual New New is very confusing to the compiler.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I can. "new" is reserved, "New" not.

Comment: Some versions of VS are not case sensitive and will except both 'New' and 'new' for the constructor.

Comment: @jdweng Ok, but I'm using VS 2017 and I've tested the options without news (I've used options in another type of publication) and I have the same problem: every new has a list of options, but I don't know how assign more than one option to one new.

Comment: Don't join. Use the navigation properties. `New` should have a property `NewOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this.   I'm not sure if I got it 100%, but it is close.  Your New class needs a property for NewOption for code below to work.

```
var news =
    (from theNew in this.context.News
    join option in this.context.NewOptions on theNew.Id equals option.NewId
    select new {theNew = theNew, option = option}).Select(x =>  new NewDto() {
        Id = x.theNew.Id,
        Title = x.theNew.Title,
        Options = x.option.Select(y => new NewOptionDto() {
            Id = y.Id,
            Option = y.Option
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I can't use ".Select" in "x.option.Select(y =>". x.option is not a collection, it's a NewOption type.

Comment: You need to add New Option as a List (or Array) to New class like : public List<NewOption> Options { get; set;}

Comment: I already have Options in the New entity. Plus, you are not using the "Options" property. @jdweng

Comment: You must have an List<Options> in the New class to get your results.  I only see Id and Title in the New class in your posting.  Then you do not need ID in the NewOption class.  You really new the New class as the parent of the NewOption Class.

Comment: I didn't post because I want execute the query without mapped relations, but in my code I already have " public virtual ICollection<NewOption> Options { get; set; }"

Comment: The mapped relationship only affects how the data is stored in the database and not how it is retrieved.  In c# you need to Options class in the New Class so your query will retrieve the data properly.